# Divide a data-frame into x roughly equal groups -- sequentially

Tags: r

I want to divide a df into x roughly equal groups, *sequentially*.

I was basically doing it like this:

```
df_1 <- df[1:10,]
df_2 <- df[11:21,]
df_3..
```

Is there a simpler way to do this, using split or slice? The important thing is, I want to maintain the order of the df, not sample from it.

Imagine I had 7000 observations, and I wanted 19 roughly equal groups.

Best!

Comment: @]d.b the last group is truncated with this option, I don't think it answers the question

Comment: `split(BOD, cut(1:nrow(BOD), 3, FALSE))`  splits data frame `BOD` into a list of three components.

Comment: ^This works nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it counts for `roughly` equal, but you can do this:

```
nobs    <- 7000
ngroups <- 17
df <- data.frame(x = sample(nobs))
set.seed(1)
df$grp <- sort(sample(1:ngroups,nobs,T)) # added the sort so the order of your df is maintained
table(df$grp)
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17 
# 436 407 410 369 417 411 440 401 431 411 356 398 390 414 443 418 448
```

then `split(df,df$grp)`

Comment: I went with the following, where "ngroups" is the number of groups I'd like to split df into:  ```split(df, cut(1:nrow(df), ngroups, FALSE))```